# How i transfer data(variables) from one html page to another page, here i am using html & django framework

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

here in my code i am displaying elements from a database using a loop
at the the user click buy button, i want to pass the particular product id to another page.
how i get the product id & how it passed to another page...

HTML page

```
{% for product in products %}

    <div class="col-md-3">


        <div class="card">
            <img src="{{product.product_image}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{product.product_name}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">₹{{product.product_price}}</p>
              <a href="{% url 'buy' %}" class="btn btn-primary">
                Buy</a>
            </div>
          </div>


    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You need to set the id of the product in the url: `/buy/<id>/`. Then in your views, you can get the object from the id in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Passing id to path

```
{% for product in products %}
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
            <img src="{{product.product_image}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{product.product_name}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">₹{{product.product_price}}</p>
              <a href="{% url 'buy' product.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">
                Buy</a>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```